# SSRS 2019 does not render images on https url in html5 format

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2019

Hy everyone,
i have some ssrs-server on version 2017 and some ssrs-server on version 2019.
All server provides the same ssrs-reports, just for different customers.
On the ssrs 2017 all works fine.

But on the ssrs-server 2019 i have the problem, the embeded images wan't be displayed.
I actually use the version 15.0.1102.911 of ssrs.
I allready found this article, it sounds like my problem: https://www.recastsoftware.com/resources/dashboards-and-missing-image-box-in-ssrs-2019/ but unfortunally it does not solve my problem.

When i analyze the url "behind" the image, i got a http url, not a https.

I use the option "rc:Toolbar=false" in the url. so the report will be rendered as a HTML5 report.
When i change this option to "rc:Toolbar=true", the report will be rendered as a RPL report and all images will be displayed as expected and the image-url is a https-url.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: did you find any resolution to this problem?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.  do you have the same problem or a solution?

Comment: Thomas, I had a similar problem and yes I found a solution for it.  Finally found out that I needed to enable strong cryptography in the registry for .net frameworks.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the SSRS configuration, the http entry had to be removed under Webservice-URL, then SSRS automatically loaded the images via the https path and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

In my case working with SSRS 2019 (v. 15.0.1102.962) in "native" mode I had to enable strong cryptography for .net framework directly in the registry.

Microsoft doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-server

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v2.0.50727]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions" = dword:00000001
"SchUseStrongCrypto" = dword:00000001
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions" = dword:00000001
"SchUseStrongCrypto" = dword:00000001

Comment: I was able to solve my problem in the meantime.
So far I had configured http as well as https in the SSRS configuration.
After I removed the http entry in the web service URL, SSRS automatically loaded the images via the https path and now everything is displayed correctly.
Why SSRS does not do this itself consistently via http or https is not comprehensible to me.